# Visual tool to resolve merge conflict with PHP Storm?

Tags: phpstorm

Is there a visual tool to resolve merge conflict with PHP Storm?

I found this documentation but it doesn't seem to be what im after
https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/resolving-text-conflicts.html

I go the menu and go VSC / Git / Resolve conflicts then I get the window below. As you can its not a visual diff.

[image]

Comment: You need to click "merge"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Clicking on the `merge` option will bring up the visual tool.

Once there, you will have the same tool appear as the `local history` or `compare differences` tools.

You need to explicitly accept or ignore each individual change when you do the merge, although there is the option to merge while ignoring any remaining differences, which results in the common ancestor + whatever changes you applied.

Comment: I recommend that you click the "apply non-conflicting changes" button as a habitual first step once you get to the merge screen. That will save you some time.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you open a file in PhpStorm, if there is conflict, there are two options you get on the top with this notification:

```
Deployed file on `server10` is changed`
```

The two options are 1. Merge 2. Download

I prefer clicking Merge that popup good UI (in version 2019.3) to manually resolve the conflict.

Showing the left side the local file with changes. Right ride the file from the server and in the middle, you can see the resultant file.

I click `apply non-conflicting changes` once I get to the screen to automatically merge non-conflicting changes to save you some time as Alex told in previous answer comments.

And then I check each conflict and resolve it manually. A tip here is keyboard shortcut F7 takes you to the next conflicting section.

One other option is clicking on the download option on the notification bar and then go to the file history (right-click on the file go to Local history > show history) and merge your changes manually with the file from your version control like SVN, git or bitbucket.